# Is there no Event.fromElement in a dragenter/dragover event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, drag-and-drop

I was playing with drag n drop in full forms (so no instant upload). I though small part was gonna be highlighting a certain fieldset when hovered over with a file. Enter `dragover` and `dragenter` events (and `dragleave` etc).

Turns out it's not such a small part. The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/epp74/

Try it out: drag over a fieldset and move around a bit. The first `over` triggers the fieldset's `dragenter` event (fieldset is yellow). The moving around after that (within the same fieldset) triggers `dragenter`s and `dragleave`s (fieldset no more yellow), which is bad.

Which is why I wanted to make what IE made for `mouseover` and `mouseout` a long time ago: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (they trigger just once). For drag events, the exact same thing applies: they should trigger only once in the exact same way. JS libraries spoof these IE events by using `Event.fromElement` and `Event.toElement` (and compare them against the event owner element). (See [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) or [Mootools](http://mootools.net/nightly/build/mootools-core.js) source for specifics.)

To make the same for drag events, I need the same `fromElement` and `toElement`. You can see in the Fiddle, I try, but I can't find them.

Anybody know where they are? Why they're not available?

I'm using Chrome primarily, which doesn't have a `fromElement` in the `dragenter` event, but **does** have a `toElement` in the `dragleave` event. In Firefox it's slightly worse (but more logical): both are empty.

Any and all ideas are so very welcome.

**edit**
After [a little more debugging](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/epp74/13/) I've found out that Chrome's `toElement` in `dragleave` isn't always correct. It's never 'bigger' than`this`, but sometimes it should be: when I leave the fieldset (`this`) to its parent form (`toElement`). When I do that, both `this` and `toElement` are the fieldset (which is incorrect, right?).

**edit** Solution:
I ended up with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/Lwd3md71/ which ignores elements in the event, and uses the event coordinates to find the element under the mouse. To make it trigger max once per animation frame, it uses requestAnimationframe, which results into 31-59 fps.

Comment: I've only skimmed your question, but do are you looking for the srcElement property of the event?

Comment: Nope. I'm looking for a correct toElement. To detect the drag leaving the fieldset I need the toElement to be outside the fieldset (like `<form>` or `<body>`). But it's always empty... The non-native mouseenter and mouseleave events (created by JS libs) use this to create mouseenter and mouseleave from mouseover and mouseout. I was trying to do the same for dragenter and dragleave. I'd need toElement and/or fromElement though. Weird. A possible solution (?) is to attach the listener to the parent element (or even `<body>`)...

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry to be such a seagull!

Comment: `e.relatedTarget` is always `null` in Chrome 23...

Comment: This may not answer your specific question, but here's your fiddle working the way I think you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/epp74/19/

Comment: That's pretty smart actually... The order of execution is very important (enter vs leave), but I assume that's the same for all browsers. Very smart indeed =) And little and readable code. Not the answer exactly, but very useful! If you want +10 rep, I'd accept this.

Comment: Glad you like it! I posted it on the off chance that it solved the problem which lead to your question. I think you should leave this question open in case someone answers your actual question. Cheers though!

Comment: (And yeah, I understand the order of enter/leave events to be pretty well standardised. I wouldn't put it past old browsers to get it wrong though...)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox provides the `relatedTarget` event property, but Chrome and Safari don't. Sadly, this issue has been open for a couple years as this [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159534) and this [Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66547).

Edit: The issue has been fixed in Chrome.

Comment: It exists, but it's always empty. Firefox was the same. They might've changed that since Dec '11 though.

Comment: You're right. Firefox doesn't have `toElement` or `fromElement`, but it does have a working `relatedTarget`. Chrome has all and none working. http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/epp74/21/

Comment: In case you're still interested, this is what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/Lwd3md71/

Comment: Chrome also provides `relatedTarget` now, but Safari does not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way of faking the relatedTarget for a "dragleave" event, which is to set a variable from the accompanying "dragenter" event -- since dragleave is always preceded by dragenter, a variable set in the latter will be available to the former:

```
var relatedTarget = null;

document.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e)
{
    relatedTarget = e.target;

}, false);
document.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e)
{
    console.log('target = ' + e.target + ' relatedTarget = ' + relatedTarget);

}, false);
```

It won't work the other way round, but you don't really need dragenter for anything else if you use it this way -- i.e. the dragleave alone is enough to tell you when the mouse is moving into, or entirely out of, a particular element.

Comment: I'm gonna try, with that, to fake `relatedTarget` in my JS lib. It sounds wrong, but it just might work. Chrome works one way, so it only has to work the other way. (Let's hope it's the possible way.) I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how a JS lib would generalize this, but it works perfectly in custom code: http://webblocks.nl/tests/dragenterleave.html Much faster than using Firefox's working method too =) Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit of a hack yeah, but it does the trick.  In my own implementation I maintain a "selection" object, which has details of the elements currently being dragged (or null when nothing is being dragged). That object also has a .related property implemented this way, and a .droptarget property which is inferred from that. I then use dragleave to updated the drag ghost whenever the droptarget changes (ie. to show a valid or invalid icon, since dropEffect and effectAllowed don't affect the cursor as they should).

Comment: In case you're still interested, this is what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/Lwd3md71/